# Get index of value for a grouped array

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

I have an array of `Ids`

```
 [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,...]
```

And another array of `values`

```
[0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,...]
```

I need to know what the zero-based index of the group of `Ids` is, where the corresponding value is `1` in JavaScript.

So for this array, we might get
`[1,2,0,...]` because that is the index of the 1 in the Values array if you were to group the Id array by their unique values.

There should only be a single 1 per group of Ids. There is a possibility that the group of Ids may be out of sequential order

(i.e.`[1,1,2,1,2,2,3,3,...]`).

But I would still want whatever the index is when the Id array is grouped.

I tried a while loop but kept getting duplicate values. Then I tried to filter my array. How can I accomplish this in JS?

Examples:

```
array 1 (IDs) : [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3] .   
array 2 (values) : [0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1] .  
result array: [1,1,3] .  

array 3 (IDs) : [1,2,1,3,1,1,2,2,3] .  
array 4 ( values) : [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1] .  
result array : [1,1,1] .
```

Comment: please add why you get `[1, 2, 0]`.

Comment: does it should be [1, 2, 5, ..] for this example or i misunderstand the problem?

Comment: Also, if the "group of Ids may be out of order" is the other array in a similar order? This is a pretty unclear question.

Comment: @NinaScholz I have tried to explain it with my recent edit. Basically, it is the index of the 1 in the Value array when you group the Id array

Comment: @M.Elkady I rephrased my question, might make more sense

Comment: @MarkMeyer Sorry if it is unclear. I meant they may not be in sequential order.

Comment: what qualifies the last result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take an index counter for the same group and get the value if a value with one is found.

> Example 3:
>
> ```
> [1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]  ids
> [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]  values
>  0  0  1  0  2  3  1  2  1   indices by group
>        ^           ^     ^   result
> ```

```js
function getIndices(ids, values) {
    var map = new Map;
    return ids.reduce((r, v, i) => {
        if (values[i] === 1) r.push(map.get(v) || 0);
        map.set(v, (map.get(v) || 0) + 1);
        return r;
    }, []);
}

// [1, 2, 0]
console.log(...getIndices([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]));

// [1, 1, 3]
console.log(...getIndices([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]));

// [1, 1, 1]
console.log(...getIndices([1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]));
```

Instead of a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), you could take an object as hash table for indexing the values.

```js
function getIndices(ids, values) {
    var hash = Object.create(null);
    return ids.reduce((r, v, i) => {
        hash[v] = hash[v] || 0;
        if (values[i] === 1) r.push(hash[v]);
        hash[v]++;
        return r;
    }, []);
}

// [1, 2, 0]
console.log(...getIndices([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]));

// [1, 1, 3]
console.log(...getIndices([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]));

// [1, 1, 1]
console.log(...getIndices([1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]));
```

Comment: Thanks @NinaScholz, you understood it perfectly. Is there any way to do it without the "Map"? That is something I am struggling to understand.